# VLA Variable-length array in Objective C (iOS), what happens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa

Maintaining some code from an iOS application, I came upon the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D inputArray[size]; // CLLocationCoordinate2D is a struct containing two doubles
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    inputArray[i] = ... ; // Fill the array
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D outputArray[size];
functionThatConvertsInputToOutput(inputArray, outputArray, size);
```

Here we are doing allocation of two struct arrays of dynamic size (cannot determine size at compile time). So called "Variable-length array", based on that SO question ( [Declare Dynamic Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506178/declare-dynamic-array) ).

I'm well aware that this does not even compile in C/C++ and when looking after similar questions, the answer is often "Use malloc" or "Use NS(Mutable)Array".

But I haven't really found the answer to the question:

**What happens in Objective C when declaring `int array[size];` ?**

The reason I'm wondering is that the piece of code I have reproduced above crashes when using VLA with reasonably large sizes (36000) and does not crash when using malloc:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *inputArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * size);
CLLocationCoordinate2D *ouputArray = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * size);
```

EDIT #1: What wikipedia says about VLA http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

EDIT #2: Crashes are `EXC_BAC_ACCESS` at odd places in `functionThatConvertsInputToOutput` or on the line calling `functionThatConvertsInputToOutput`.

Comment: Objective-C is based on C, so it **is** supported in both C and Objective-C.  If you don't like it (I don't) then use `malloc()` and friends.

Comment: That is not that I don't like it. Only, I seem to get overflow-related crashes using VLA and I don't really understand why.

Comment: I think Wil Shipley has answered that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s very likely it’s sticking the memory for the array on the stack, which is why you’re crashing when you blow up the stack by 36,000 * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D).

Comment: Ok, looks like the stack for an iOS secondary thread is about 512KB, so max 32'000 records of my 16bytes struct. Seems to explain the issue. Thanks :)