# Missing '[' at start of message send expression

Tags: objective-c, syntax-error

I am getting this error message and matched my brackets and couldn't find anything wrong. Can you find what's wrong? I really need help. Please. The error I am getting is this "Missing '[' at start of message send expression" I have commented where it occurs down near the end of my code. Please help me.

Thank you.

```
@interface HomeViewOne ()

@end

@implementation HomeViewOne

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)switchScreenHome:(id)sender {

    //Code to switch screen from main menu to game
    ViewController *view [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  //My error is on this line, it says Missing '[' at start of message send expression
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: I moved the stack trace to the relevant follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737897/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-can-someone-help-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing something useful, like an `=`.

Thus the `[..]` is *not* parsed in a meaningful fashion (i.e. as an expression used in an assignment) and results in the given syntax error.

---

The code is actually parsed as an variable array declaration, consider

```
X* x[..];
```

where `..` is

```
[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil
```

which results in "Missing '[' at start of message send expression", just as if that code appeared in a statement by itself. Adding another pair of `[]`'s would "fix" that, and actually declare a [variable-length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089329/vla-variable-length-array-in-objective-c-ios-what-happens). However, you definetly don't want a VLA here.. just add the assignment operator already.

Answer (score 1):

That line should be:

```
ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  //My error is on this line, it says Missing '[' at start of message send expression
```

you need to add a "`=`".

Answer (score 1):

The line with the error should actually be:

```
ViewController *view = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Note the '=' character

Comment: This helped take the error away. THANKS. But now when I run it it goes to the AppDelegate.h and shows me an error saying Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: you mean you get a crash in main? or does running fail?

Comment: I get a crash in main.

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: Do you get an exception? Does it say anything in your console beside sigabrt? Is this both on simulator and device?

Comment: I do get one I will post it in my code because it is to long to post in comment.

Comment: Please see the follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737897/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-can-someone-help-me)